# How do I setup MPD correctly?

Tags: debian, media

I want to set up MPD on my Raspberry Pi. I am using latest the Debian Wheezy, and I want MPD to run on the network and to listen to any interface.
So far I've installed it:

```
sudo apt-get install mpd
```

and set these variables in /etc/mpd.conf

```
music_directory "/mnt/Music"
bind_to_address "::"
```

and somehow got it working and playing my music. But after a reboot, it did not start automatically and my client (gmpc) does not see anything in the database. When I try to update the database (via gmpc), it says that it is already updating, but actually it is not updating, because the mpd process is consuming only 0.3 %cpu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've changed bind_to_address to "any" and set mpd to be /var/run/mpd owner.

```
sudo chown mpd /var/run/mpd
```

and gave 755 permissions to /var/run/mpd/pid file

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/run/mpd/pid
```

Now it is working perfectly.